# Adding polygons to Tableau from Open Street Map

Tags: tableau-api, geojson

I've been trying to add districts to my global map in Tableau. I followed the instructions [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/183248/getting-polygon-boundaries-of-city-in-json-from-google-maps-api) to extract the coordinates for e.g. Diyala governorate in Iraq from Open Street Map (OSM 3242294). I download the GeoJSON, but when I load it to Tableau, it shows it as mixed geometry, which I understand Tableau doesn't support.

If it's mixed geometry, that means the coordinates are not just a single polygon right? Why is that (because when I plug in coordinates on geojson.io it appears to be a single polygon)? And is there a way I can somehow 'convert' the polygon into a format that will load properly in Tableau? I'm very new to all of this and came across a few possible similar answers about changing multipolygons to polygons, but really didn't get it. Is anyone able to help me understand?

Answer (score 0):

You need to import each geometry type separately. Then need to join them by matching at least 1 column. That column no needs to be relevant, you can add both files to column called "flag" and just insert 1 to all rows to be able to match both data.

After you separately added points and polygons, you should drag drop geometry for polygons and lat long for points to the "mark" section. From there you can customize both polygons and points in a single map.

Comment: Thanks Omur - are you able to break down the steps into more detail? For example, I can't work out how to import the different geometry types separately or even what you're referring to with rows and columns.